# When to terminate search for path in an infinite grid

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, graph-traversal

I'm learning shortest path algorithms like Dijkstra's, BFS, etc. I understand on a 2D finite grid there are boundary conditions (i.e. size of the grid) that help terminate the algorithm and keep it in a certain scope/range. However when expanding this to an infinite 2D grid, I don't understand when (say using BFS as an example) to conclude that a path simple doesn't exist without having the algorithm run infinitely since I can't use grid size as a boundary condition. Is there some kind of formula that can be used in these cases? Also, take into account that there could be obstacles along the path too so the path distance can vary from different origins to destinations.

I've considered trying to take the absolute value of the difference between the coordinate points and raising it to some power as a way of setting an upper limit of steps taken before considering that a path must not exist, but this approach is obviously lacking and incorrect to say it bluntly since it doesn't work for many cases.

I apologize if my question is confusing. I'll restate it here: basically, how do I know when to assume a path from an origin to a destination doesn't exist in an infinite 2D grid?

Comment: *"How do I know when ... a path ... doesn't exist in an infinite 2D grid?"* Answer: you don't. There is no relation between the path length, and the distance between the coordinates. Consider two points a small distance apart vertically, but separated from each other by an almost infinite horizontal wall. Or two points an almost infinite distance apart, but with no obstacles between them. In the first case, the ratio of path length to distance is nearly infinite. In the second case, the ratio is 1. So no formula will relate distance to maximum path length.

Comment: The bottom line is that part of software design is to put reasonable constraints on the problem to be solved. Without constraints, there is no solution.

Answer (score 2):

Short version is that you don't.

Here is a longer version.  Suppose that I supply you with a program that identifies which spots in the grid are to be cut, and your job is to figure out whether or not there is a path from A to B.  I can easily provide you with a program X such that a path will exist if and only if program Y eventually halts.  (Just draw a horizontal line of length 2*running time of program Y + 1, then ask you go to from (0, -1) to (0, 1).)  If you could write your program successfully, then between us we've just solve [the Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), which is known to be impossible.